# how to retrive data from more than one table in mvc asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to show list of order details including count of ordered material and name of customer.
There are three tables order_details, order_item_details and customer_details

for this scenario how to create view model and linq

my db structure

customer_details === customer_id,customer_name

||||| 
order_details === order_id, order_number, customer_id

||||| 
order_item_details === order_item_id, order_id , item_id

and i want to show------
order_details.order_number, customer_details.customer_name, count(order_item_details.order_item_id)

Comment: You will need to provide more information. How are all these tables linked together? What field names do you specifically want to show?

Comment: customer_details === customer_id,customer_name |||||        order_details === order_id, order_number, customer_id |||||            order_item_details === order_item_id, order_id , item_id

Comment: and i want to show------order_details.order_number, customer_details.customer_name, count(order_item_details.order_item_id)

Comment: why not put it in your question so its actually easy for people to read

Answer (score 0):

Create a view in your database that links the three tables appropriately, then point your ORM (EF?) at the view, and you will get a read-only view of your table with appropriate models.  If what you're doing is particularly complex, you can create a stored procedure and use the same technique.

If you are in fact using Entity Framework, here's an SO answer that tells you how to create custom entities in EF 4 (first answer by Kevin Castle):

[Entity framework 3.5, mapping stored procedure results to custom entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902851/entity-framework-3-5-mapping-stored-procedure-results-to-custom-entity)